# Objective-C Multiple Callbacks To Same Function

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, delegates

Right now I have a view controller that handles a lot of network requests. They are each a subclass of a `NetworkRequest` class and this view controller is the delegate of all of them. It implements one callback function, `networkRequestDidFinish`.

The problem is that all these network requests are separate objects, and they will all call that same function. What is the proper way to design this? Right now I go through a bunch of if statements in `networkRequestDidFinish` to see what kind of network request returned. It feels wrong though, but I am not sure what is conventional to do in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have to do something different depending on what subclass of `NetworkRequest` comes back? If so, how different? (I know, that's a weird question)

Answer (score 0):

One useful pattern here is to be sure that the delegate methods pass `self` to the view controller. It sounds like you might already be doing this - if you're using a series of `if` statements, you probably have a pointer to the relevant `NetworkRequest`. If you aren't, or are not sure, read on.

You see this pattern pretty much wherever delegation is used. As an arbitrary example, take the [UITableViewDelegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). The first argument of each of the delegate methods is a `UITableView`. For example:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

When a `UITableView` instance calls this delegate method, it passes `self` as that first argument. It does something like:

```
[self.delegate tableView:self heightForRowAtIndexPath:0];
```

Then, the delegate knows *which* `UITableView` it's dealing with, because it has a pointer dropped in its lap, as the argument `tableView`.

In your case, I would start by adding a parameter to the delegate method `networkRequestDidFinish`, changing its signature to:

```
- (void)networkRequestDidFinish:(NetworkRequest *)networkRequest
```

That way you can tell *which* instance of `NetworkRequest` has called the delegate method.

---

Already had that, or that's not good enough? Well, the next thing I'd say would be to consider whether you really need to perform different actions based on the actual class of the `NetworkRequest` instance that's calling the delegate method. If you're just passing along the data, the answer is probably no. For example:

```
- (void)networkRequestDidFinish:(NetworkRequest *)networkRequest {
    [self processData:networkRequest.data];
}
```

That method doesn't care what class `networkRequest` really is. But you seem to care, since you're doing "a bunch of `if` statements." Then I would say that it might be a mistake to have them all hitting one delegate method. Instead, you might want to get rid of a delegate on `NetworkRequest`, and instead add a protocol to each of the subclasses of that class, specific to the subclass.

*What?*

Let's look at an example.

Imagine that one of the subclasses of `NetworkRequest` is `FooNetworkRequest` which, of course, requests foos. Its header might look like this:

```
// stuff...
@protocol FooNetworkRequestDelegate
- (void)fooNetworkRequestDidFinish:(FooNetworkRequest *)fooNetworkRequest;
@end

@interface FooNetworkRequest : NetworkRequest
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<FooNetworkRequestDelegate> delegate;
// stuff...
@end
```

You apply a similar treatment to all the other subclasses of `NetworkRequest`. Then, your view controller would adopt each of these protocols, and have a separate method for each subclass of `NetworkRequest`.

---

That still seems kind of dirty, right? It does to me. Maybe this is a hint that your view controller is trying to handle too many things at once. You should consider trying to spread out the responsibility for all these `NetworkRequest` subclasses to multiple view controller or model classes.

If that's not an option, you can at least make your view controller's source a little easier to read by using one or more categories. Put your view controller's main behavior in its `.m` file, as usual, and then create a category on that view controller that adopts the proper protocol(s) and handles the requests.

Answer (score 0):

There are generally 2 nice procedures.

1. You can use block instead of the delegate. That means you can send a block to your request class either when instancing it or when you make the request.
2. Use a target/selector pair system to make it look kind of like adding a target to an `UIButton`. `NSInvocation` should do the trick.